# WPF: How to remove textbox created dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating multiple textbox, I was wondering since I created these textbox dynamically how would I remove them or even update them?

For example in code

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Name = "Temp"
```

How would I remove or update textbox `Temp`

I cannot called `Temp.Text = "Test"`

Also I do not have access to tb.Text. I have created a bunch of textboxes and named them by a number `textbox_1`. When a certain button is clicked I want to update the textbox that is clicked.

Comment: You will use it as tb.Text="your text". As far as how to remove, you need to remove it from the Children/Items of its parent container.

Comment: "When a certain button is clicked I want to update the textbox that is clicked." Are you clicking a button or textbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find that textbox from the container using `Name` like:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox) this.someStackPanel.FindName("Temp");
```

then later

```
tb.Text = "Test";
```

To remove it you can do:

```
//First find the TextBox
TextBox tb = (TextBox) this.someStackPanel.FindName("Temp");
//Then remove it 
this.someStackPanel.Children.Remove(tb);
```

Comment: Sweet I think this is what I am looking for!

Comment: Thank I Will accept it as the answer as soon as the time is up.

Comment: @AustinTruong In the future, google is your friend. This is extremely simple stuff that can be answered by looking at documentation or the numerous examples that already exist of exactly this.

Comment: @tnw, Thank you for the advice. I did try to google it haha, I probably did not google the right keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
parent.RegisterName("Temp", tb);
```

on the parent after creating the TextBox to register the name.

When you want to find the TextBox, call

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox) parent.FindName("Temp")
```

to get the TextBox.